# Encryption using SHA1 and private key in JDK 6

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am trying to do Encryption using SHA1 and private key in JDK 1.6.0_35.

But I am getting following exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting SHA1

the same code works for AES. Here is the code :

```
public class ExecuteEncryptDecryptSample {
        private static String method="SHA1"; 
        public static SecretKeySpec getKeySpec() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
            File f = new File("sample_aes_key");
        SecretKey key = null;
        SecretKeySpec spec = null;
        if (f.exists()) {
            new FileInputStream(f).read(bytes);
        } else {
            //KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("SHA1");//PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(method);
            kgen.init(256);
            key = kgen.generateKey();
            bytes = key.getEncoded();
            new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes);

        }
        spec = new SecretKeySpec(bytes,method);
        return spec;
    }
    public static void encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec spec = getKeySpec();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(method);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, spec);
        BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();
        System.out.println(enc.encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes())));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "1234000156237828282873773";
        //Security security;
        //security.getProviders();
        System.out.println();
        encrypt(text);
    }
}
```

Is there any provider for SHA1 in jdk 6..?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as encryption with SHA-1. Do you mean hashing?

Answer (score 1):

SHA-1 is a secure hash algorithm. It's not a key derivation function even if it is sometimes used as one. So although you can use `MessageDigest` with algorithm `"SHA-1"`, you cannot use a `KeyGenerator` with `"SHA-1"`.

If you want to generate keys for compatibility reasons then you may use `MessageDigest` with `"SHA-1"` and take the first bytes of the output (as many as needed to create the key). After that you can use e.g. `SecretKeySpec(firstBytes, "AES")` or `SecretKeyFactory` for 3DES keys.

Comment: Can u plz share code that encrypt a string using SHA1. I had tried the way you told, but I am not getting the required output.

Comment: SHA1 is a secure hash algorithm, it is not a cipher either. So you cannot encrypt with SHA1 (well, unless you turn it into a stream cipher, but that's probably not what you meant). And I cannot show code if I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh What owlstead is saying, simply put, is that you are trying to find the starter button on your bicycle ;) SHA1 is not an encryption algorithm, therefore, you cannot encrypt with it. You can *hash* with it, but that is a one-way street, meaning you will not be able to decrypt it (or de*hash* it, for that matter) later.

Comment: @owlstead I need a program that converts a sting into hash using Base64 encding with SHA1

Comment: So use `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(string.getBytes("UTF-8"))` and then use a library (not a Sun internal class as you do now, try Apache codec library) to convert the result into base 64. You may want to use another character encoding than UTF-8 - you haven't specified one in the question or comments.

Comment: Any luck with this? How are you faring?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asked to do symmetric key encryption with SHA1, then this possibly means
that you should encrypt with a symmetric key (e.g. AES) and authenticate with HMACSHA1.
The class to use for the authentication would be

javax.crypto.Mac

(not MessageDigest) and the algorithm would be "HMACSHA1" not ("SHA1").
Of course that is a lot of guessing, an unfortunately I don't have my crystal ball with me today, so I could be wrong. (E.g., it could also be a horrible abuse of crypto terms and mean you should hash with SHA1 and sign with RSA, where of course using SHA1 would no longer be appropriate.)

Answer (score -2):

Try to list all entries of keystore, it looks like the SHA is not present in the key store while AES is. If it is not present, try adding the value to the keystore and test again.

Comment: SHA - or more precisely SHA-1 is a hash algorithm. It is not a key and can not be present in any key store (I don't see a key store in the question, maybe you meant the provider?)

Comment: Can u plz share simple java code that encrypt a string using base64 and SHA1. I had tried the way you told, but I am not getting the required output.